# Can I change the my existing square columns to round?

Tags: replacement

My home is cape cod without the roof gables with a long front porch that spans the length of the house.  I'd like to change my existing columns from square to round just for a different look. Are there any structural issues I should be concerned with?

Comment: My original ideaI was to replace  existing wood columns with cylindrical, but I was told another option is wrapping existing,but I wasnt clear if I could wrap with cylindrical. How do I post a picture?

Answer (score 1):

Changing from square to round posts should not be a structural problem as long as it’s 1) the same cross sectional area or larger, 2) same species of wood or a stronger species, 3) same grade of wood or better.

Of course the connections will need to be the same or better.

Comment: I believe the wood would be more expensive in the round.  What other options are there?

Comment: Any size steel post that matches the size (edge) of the wood post will work. A fiberglass post is available, but it’s not structural. The fiberglass posts are usually larger and hollow, but you could install it over a square wood post or round steel post, to give the “look” you’re after.